# Can't gain access to SFTP after changes in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Tags: ssh, sftp

I simply trying to make some changes in sshd_config file with port and other line (don't remember which one) and now I can't log in to my SFTP.
It is possible to make some changes in this file using SSH command?
Maybe is possible to remove old file and upload new default one?

OS: CentOS 6.5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which distro are you using ?

Comment: Sorry, is CentOS 6.5

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you don't have backups so.

First thing to check is if there is a /etc/ssh/sshd_config.rpmnew, if there is it's an original as supplied sshd_config simply copy it over sshd_config and restart the service.

On CentOS you can use rpm to find which package the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file is in e.g.

```
rpm -qf /etc/ssh/sshd_config
openssh-server-5.3p1-94.el6.x86_64
```

So we need to reinstall openssh-server but first make a copy of the sshd_config file and delete it

```
 cp sshd_config sshd_config.safe
 rm sshd_config
 yum reinstall openssh-server
```

Then restart the service.

Take aways:

- Backuos are your friend.
- Make backups of the files your're fiddling with especially if you don't know what your're doing.

Comment: When I'm putting cp sshd_config sshd_config.safe I receive" cp: can't make stat on 'sshd_config'. There is no file and folder. This file I have on serv: openssh-server-5.3p1-94.el6.x86_64

Comment: Ok so it doesn't exist just reinstall the package - it looks like you managed to delete it somehow.

Comment: yum reinstall openssh-server It's done. After this I reboot VPS but anyway I still can't connect with SFTP using default settings. I have old sshd_config file backuped on my desktop but I can't upload this without SFTP access :(

Comment: Yep, after reinstalling and restarting (# service sshd restart) still can't log in to SFTP. So teamspeak can't connect with my serv. too... .

Comment: Of course you can upload it, use scp.

Comment: But if I have this file on my desktop how should I write path to this file? ssh]# scp C:\Desktop\sshd_config root@vps75870:/etc/ssh/
ssh: Could not resolve hostname C: No address associated with hostname

Comment: I think it's time to start reading some docs.

Comment: Finally in this file sshd_config I'm changing port from 22 to 49155 and change line with 'subsystem' for this one: Subsystem sftp internal-sftp. That's why I can't gain access to SFTP.

Comment: # scp //Users/Gicu/Desktop/sshd_config root@vps75870:/etc/ssh/
root@vps75870's password:
//Users/Gicu/Desktop/sshd_config: No such file or directory

Comment: OK It's work!. I'm using this instructions: [link](http://www.nairabytes.net/index.php/blog/62-geek/297-how-to-transfer-files-between-linux-and-windows-using-putty)

Comment: Ofter this my teamspeak can't connect with my server but on serv. ts3 in up when I checked... Any advice? [root@vps75870 ~]# service teamspeak restart
Stopping the TeamSpeak 3 server..done
Starting the TeamSpeak 3 server
TeamSpeak 3 server started, for details please view the log file
[root@vps75870 ~]# service teamspeak status
Server is running

Comment: Your question was about how to recover sshd_config - That is answered. Everything else is different questions I don't care to are about.